# How to use the "Make a Copy" trick when sharing a Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I want to share a Google Forms file with customers and, when each one of them open it, I want the file to automatically ask them if they want a copy of the file in their own directory.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created and saved your form with your preferred sharing parameters (add collaborators/who has access), and have a copy of the URL for sharing replace the word "edit" in the URL with the word "copy" before sending it to anyone.  Leave the rest of the URL as is both before and (if applicable) after the word "edit."

example 1:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uX-GobbleDeeGook.ll/edit
changes to
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uX-GobbleDeeGook.ll/copy

example 2:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uX-EatSlowlyDeeGook.ll/edit?usp=sharing
changes to
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uX-EatSlowlyDeeGook.ll/copy?usp=sharing